# How to populate google visualization data table from MySQL database with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-visualization

````
```
<?php
// open database connection
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', '', '');
// sql query
$result = mysql_query($connection, "SELECET name, author, publisher, yearOfPublish, ISBN 
FROM books");
if(!$connection) {
    die("Connection failer: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected Succes";
?>

// html code 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Main Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['table']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);
// draw table function
function drawTable() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
// add columns
data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
data.addColumn('string', 'Author');
data.addColumn('string', 'Publisher');
data.addColumn('number', 'Year Of Publish');
data.addColumn('number', 'ISBN');
// add rows
data.addRows([
// retrieve data from database
]);
...
```
````

I have a database where I keep book information, and I am trying to retrieve those book information and put them into a google data table. I successfully opened connection with the database. However, I do not know how I am going to execute the query and get the data from the database.

Comment: Do you know how to make a request with `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest`? That way you can request the data from the server and send the data from the DB as JSON. JavaScript can then read that data and use it for your visualization table.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I do not know how those work, but I will try to google them and find a way, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function drawTable() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Title', 'Author', 'Publisher', 'Year Of Publish', 'ISBN'],
        <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {?>
        ['<?php echo $row['name']?>' , '<?php echo $row['author']?>', '<?php echo $row['publisher']?>', '<?php echo $row['yearOfPublish']?>', '<?php echo $row['ISBN']?>'],
        <?php } ?>
    ]);
    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

    table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, width: '50%', height: '50%'});
}
```

I found a solution